# UITableViewCells loaded from NIB always nil

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview, nib

I'm trying to create a simple form using a `UITableViewController` as documented in the Apple Developer Documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).

What I'm trying to do is located in the section entitled: "The Technique for Static Row Content"

I've created a couple of `UITableViewCells` and added them to my nib, but when I try and access them to add them to the `UITableView` (in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method) they are always null.

It's like they are not being properly loaded from the nib. I've double/triple/quadruple checked my code to make sure I'm doing it exactly as detailed in the docs, but no luck.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you've connected the IBOutlets in the nib file?

In your ViewController.h file you should have:

```
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *specialCell1;
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *specialCell2;
```

and then each of these should be "wired up" to the corresponding cell in the nib file.  If not, they won't exist!

Comment: I've got that...  It still doesn't work.   I just tried a very simple test project and it worked fine, so I think it's something about how I'm creating the parent view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out...

When I added my parent view controller, I was using the simple "init".   Switching to "initWithNibName" resolved the issue...

Still learning... :)

Comment: Graaaah these answers drive me mad! This is the second question I've found for the exact same problem I have, and it's the second question that's closed with a "nevermind, found it", completely lacking an explanation I can understand. :( 

I know that I need to call initWithNibName _somewhere_, but I can't understand where and how. This is my root controller, so it can't be in the controller above that, and it apparently is not in any of the init methods, because that doesn't work as well.

Sorry, I just needed to vent. Not expecting an answer.